# mysql UNION statement works weird

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have this select funtion in mysql, however it seems to work a bit weird. First off in phpmyadmin, if I run the first and second sperately it gives me 4 from the first select and 1 from the second. This is the way I would like to have it, but when I run it with the union, I get every item in the table. Even worse is when I run it in php with mysqli, because there it just stops working. What could go wrong here?

```
SELECT appID, hours FROM games ORDER BY hours DESC LIMIT 4
UNION
SELECT appID, hours FROM games WHERE appID = 221380
```

Comment: do you really need UNION? why not just not add the `WHERE` clause in the first and forget about the other one? `SELECT appID, hours FROM games WHERE appID = 221380 ORDER BY hours DESC LIMIT 4`

Comment: *"Even worse is when I run it in php with mysqli, because there it just stops working."* - that's unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then I would only get the one with id 221380, I however would like to have the top 4 and compare those to id 221380. So that is why I need multiple select statements. juergen answered it already though.

Comment: ah ok, I understand. However, you said: *"Even worse is when I run it in php with mysqli, because there it just stops working."* - or has that been resolved?

Comment: The server returned an error when I ran the php file with that statement

Comment: so, the question hasn't been completely solved then

Comment: Yes, I dont know why it didnt select them all with mysqli. now it does, but it is working again :) thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses and `union all`

```
(SELECT appID, hours FROM games ORDER BY hours DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT appID, hours FROM games WHERE appID = 221380)
```